# In OpenLayers3 how would I prevent a feature from moving in front of other features when selected?

Tags: openlayers-3

The hierarchy I'm using looks something like this:

```
FRONT  
1 - layer with several features (e.g. point data)  
2 - layer with several features (e.g. path data)  
3 - layer with several features (e.g. region data)  
BACK
```

When the user selects a feature in layer 3 based on an `ol.interaction.Select` the default behavior is to render the selected feature in front of layer 1. How can I prevent this re-ordering?

Answer (score 0):

I had a nearly similiar problem, when i selected the region - the points and other vector geometries were hidden behind the selected feature. In my usecase an special styling with transparent filling was the solution. 
If you want a solution based on the layer rendering i would suggest to handle it with the ZIndex. The ol.interaction.Select doesn't provide a setZIndex but if you take a look on the source code (https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.13.0/src/ol/interaction/selectinteraction.js) you can see that the interaction save the selected feature in an unmanaged Layer which you can access on different ways (map.getLayers().getArray().forEach .... or sth) and i'm sure there you can set the ZIndex. Note default zIndex is 0 and a higher Index will render the layer above and lower one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the select interaction works in ol3.  The selected feature is `marked` for being skipped in rendering.  In other words, it disappears from the original layer it comes from upon re-rendering after being selected.

It is then added to an other layer that is actually not added to the map using the conventional `map.addLayer` method, but set to the map using `layer.setMap`.  The layer ends up being drawn on top of all the others, resulting the "selected" feature to be on top of everything else.

This architecture was decided to improve performance.  However, you can easily achieve what you want, i.e. have the clicked feature stay where it is and change its style, by simply using the `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` method and implement your own concept of selection there.  It would be slower, but simple enough to accomplish what you want.